# create wordpress plugin with zend framework 2

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, zend-framework2

I want to develop a membership plugin under wordpress and for this I want to use zend framework 2.

Does anyone managed to create a wordpress plugin using zend framework 2?
I'm new to zf and I do not know how and where to start from.
I tried to start from zend skeleton application but got stuck at add_menu_pages and displaying a simple dashboard.

Can anyone give me some ideas or links.
Thanks!

**Updated**!

I managed to get this working! I just needed to use a PhpRenderer. For those who need a little more help here is how I did:

I created a class that manages all admin area. On class init I called a method that created menu pages( in this method simply add_menu_pages() and instead of callback_function I called a new method, manage_pages, that, wel... manages pages, but you can do it as you desire) and then I initiated the view, like this:

```
  $this->view = new PhpRenderer();  
  $this->map = new Resolver\TemplateMapResolver(array(
        'template_name' => 'template_path',
        'template2_name'=> 'template2_path')); //this is for handling view templates a little easier
  $this->resolver = new Resolver\TemplateMapResolver($this->map);
  $this->view->setResolver($this->resolver);       
  $this->model    = new ViewModel();
```

Further, in manage_pages method, for each page I have, I added its own template and variables I needed

```
 $this->model->setTemplate('template_name'); 
 $this->model->setVariable('variable_name', value);
```

As for displaying template, you just have to write this piece of code:

```
 echo $this->view->render($this->model);
```

In the template files you can access variables using `$this->variable_name`
Also you can insert another template using `$this->partial( 'template2_name', assoc_arrray_of_variables_to_be_passed_to_template )`.

And this is it! If you have any questions, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wordpress plugin you can use, search "wopzen2" or "wordpress and zend framework 2 integration" on Google, with this solution, you can use the following code inside the php wordpress code:

`global $wpzf2plugin;
    $render=$wpzf2plugin->render('/application/index/contactform');
    echo $render;`

This code calls the contactform action, if you are familiar with zendframework I think you are going to understand it.

This plugin is dedicated to developers.

You can get a free version of the plugin via support center.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you

reference link:
[Example codes](http://www.wordpresszendframework2.com/code-examples/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank for your answers, but I managed to do it by myself. I updated the question with solution!

Comment: Hi, teoflavian, thanks for update, but i have one question, your solution is right but that way can you use the viewhelpers and layout too?? I would like be in contact with you. Anyway congratulations!!.